Relative paths do not work anymore after rewriting requests
I am new to web development and I am trying to understand how to protect certain files from user direct access.
I want to redirect all requests to "index.php" and give access to a file with sensitive information (such as an image) based on a certain condition (like the user's credentials).
To do this, I have created an ".htaccess" file.
The path to "index.php", ".htaccess" and "image.png" is "C:\xampp\htdocs\project".
I also modified httpd.conf to "AllowOverride All" and the redirecting works fine.
The problem is that the relative path to that file does not work.
".htaccess":
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /project/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php

"index.php":
<body>
    <?php
        $routes = ["/project/image.png"];
        $user_logged_in = true;

        if(in_array($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $routes) && $user_logged_in)
            echo "<img src=\"image.png\">";
    ?>
</body>

The image is not loading (broken image icon). How can I accomplish this?
Where can I find a beginner friendly documentation about this topic?
I modified the image path in many ways but nothing seems to work.

The problem is that you're routing ALL requests through your front controller (index.php). That includes your subsequent request to image.png. You're getting the broken image icon because <img> elements expect some kind of image response, but instead the request is likely resulting in an HTML response containing empty <body> tags. You can test this by navigating to http://your.domain.here/image.png and opening up your inspector to look at the response you're getting.

Either way, what you're trying to do is admirable, but I think it's a little more advanced than you realize. Arriving at the answer will require a deeper understanding of the request / response lifecycle, as well as how to use a server-side language to serve different response types based on the criteria you're after. I don't think anybody here can give you a succinct answer, since even a minimal solution to the question you're asking will require a fair bit of code.

As an aside, if you want to cheat a little and get around the image request, you can look into base64 encoding the image file you're referencing and rendering the resulting data in your image element instead of a URL path. It'll be uglier, but it can circumvent the issue you're seeing currently.

The point was that I have a "private_information.extension" file (not just some simple asset) in the "project" directory and I wanted to understand how to protect its content from unauthorised users.
Thanks for the response.

Usually, you'd put such files one level above the public directory, so that they are not reachable via HTTP in the first place. If your hosting setup doesn't allow for that, then you can indeed rewrite those requests to a script - but then your script is responsible for delivering the file content to the client, when requested. That means outputting the appropriate headers first (Content-Type at least, for most use cases), and then the file content after those.

The technique for protecting sensitive files from direct HTTP access is to put them above the root directory and access them with PHP based on certain conditions (e.g. user's credentials) as C3roe explained. Thank you, C3roe!
